# Is glass exposed to flame ever safe again?

Tags: safety

My son has exposed a glass container to the stove's flame. He didn't know it's not supposed to be used like that.

The container is good for going into the oven, but not for being exposed directly to flames.

I understand it's now at high risk of shattering violently as it cools, sending pieces flying. We've taken some precautions.

My question is: is it permanently ruined (trash) now, or is it safe to use again if it stays whole after some time, or some procedure? How long, or what procedure?

Comment: Any chance that it was Pyrex’s ‘visions’ line?  They made stovetop stuff, so if it’s that, it might be okay: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visions_(cookware)

Comment: "it's now at high risk of shattering violently as it cools, sending pieces flying." There is no chance of this happening

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your stove is powerful enough to break some glass containers by creating a severe enough temperature gradient. But it is nowhere near powerful enough to do anything *interesting* to glass. It can’t *change* it in any way, other than breaking it.

You’re not supposed to hit glass containers with hammers either. But if a hammer accidentally fell on a glass container, and it didn’t break, you wouldn’t think twice about continuing to use it. It’s the same thing here.

Comment: Not _exactly_ the same, but close enough.